# Ren-py: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: python, renpy

I want the images to be loaded depending on a variable "ImgVal"

```
$ ImgVal = []
$ image bob = "b_neutral_%s.png" % ImgVal
$ image bob_sad = "b_sad_%s.png" % ImgVal
$ image bob_happy = "b_happy_%s.png" % ImgVal
```

Comment: Please provide us with more information (what's the verbatim error message) - what's the question anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value passed by the `%` operator has to be of type string (or a dictionary, if you use `%(val_name)s` instead of `%s`).

For example:

```
ImgVal = 1
# some calculation to evaluate Imgval
print "b_neutral_%s.png" % str(ImgVal) # cast ImgVal from int to str
```

Note that if you want to use a array you'll need some construct like this:

```
ImgVal = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in ImgVal:
    print "b_neutral_%s.png" % str(i)
```

Edit:

I've never worked with renpy, but looking in the documentation about [using python](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/python.html), you are using the `$` sign incorrectly, you should only use it for raw python code. The `%` operator is python only, therefore you'll have to use it and evaluate the string, then pass it to renpy. This could **probably** work:

```
$ ImgVal = "h1c1"
$ img_str = "b_neutral_%s.png" % ImgVal
image bob = img_str
$ img_str = "b_sad_%s.png" % ImgVal
image bob_sad = img_str
$ img_str = "b_happy_%s.png" % ImgVal
image bob_happy = img_str
```

The only thing I can tell you for sure is that you were using `$` incorrectly and that your string formatting was wrong in your first example.

Comment: Thank you, and yeah my English ins't that great. I tried what you said but I get this eerror:  while loading <'Image' 'b_neutral_%(ImgVal)s.png'>: IOError: Couldn't find file 'b_neutral_%(ImgVal)s.png'.

Comment: The variable should hold this: "h1c1" from a _return

Comment: Then you are not templating correctly. Can you update your question and provide more code? Or tell me more specifically what exaclty you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to load difference images by only changing the variable, this is in Ren-py btw so that's a lot of code already written.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but it works if I do this:    image bob = "b_neutral_%s.png" % "h1c1"

Comment: I've edited my answer but at this point I'm not sure if your approach is doable that way.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but thank you for your help I appreciate it.